# R graphics: stacked dots with polar coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using RStudio, I'm attempting to:
(1) plot **dots without overlap**, because I want to place numbers in each of them,
(2) considering that **both x and y axes are categorical**, and
(3) on a **polar/spiderweb coordinate** plot

Here is my data:

```
dtgr <- data.frame(
  gbf_ttl = c("Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal C", "Goal D", "Target 1", "Target 1", "Target 2", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 3", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 6", "Target 7", "Target 8", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 13", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 16", "Target 18", "Target 18", "Target 18", "Target 19", "Target 20", "Target 20", "Target 21", "Target 21", "Goal A", "Goal A", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Goal C", "Target 1", "Target 2", "Target 3", "Target 4", "Target 4", "Target 5", "Target 5", "Target 7", "Target 8", "Target 9", "Target 9", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 10", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 11", "Target 13", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 14", "Target 18", "Target 21", "Target 21", "Target 22", "Target 22", "Target 23", "Goal B", "Goal B", "Target 6", "Target 12", "Target 15", "Target 17"), 
  nbt_ttll = c("1.1", "2.1", "3.3", "5.1", "5.2", "6.1", "6.2", "7.4", "7.5", "7.6", "7.7", "10.1", "12.1", "13.1", "14.1", "15.2", "17.1", "19", "2.2", "3.3", "3.4", "6.2", "6.3", "7.5", "7.7", "8.1", "12.1", "13.1", "17.1", "18.1", "19", "13.1", "20", "5.1", "7.6", "5.1", "1.1", "3.3", "5.1", "6.1", "7.6", "10.1", "15.1", "15.2", "1.1", "5.1", "5.2", "7.6", "10.1", "13.1", "14.1", "15.1", "15.2", "1.1", "6.2", "7.5", "7.6", "10.1", "11.1", "13.1", "9.1", "7.5", "6.1", "1.1", "3.4", "5.1", "6.2", "6.3", "7.5", "7.6", "7.7", "10.1", "11.1", "12.1", "13.1", "14.1", "15.1", "17.1", "1.1", "2.1", "3.4", "5.1", "6.2", "6.3", "7.3", "7.7", "10.1", "11.1", "13.1", "15.1", "15.2", "17.1", "1.1", "5.1", "6.1", "7.6", "7.7", "8.1", "10.1", "13.1", "15.1", "17.1", "19", "2.1", "1.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "5.1", "5.2", "7.5", "7.6", "10.1", "13.1", "15.1", "16.1", "17.1", "18.1", "19", "20", "1.1", "3.2", "3.4", "14.1", "20", "1.1", "19", "2.1", "19", "11.1", "15.1", "1.1", "2.1", "5.1", "5.2", "6.1", "7.6", "10.1", "14.1", "15.1", "18.2", "11.1", "15.2", "11.1", "11.1", "12.1", "6.1", "18.2", "8.1", "15.2", "6.1", "18.2", "2.2", "6.1", "7.1", "7.5", "7.6", "11.1", "14.1", "15.2", "16.1", "2.1", "2.2", "11.1", "14.1", "15.2", "3.3", "18.1", "18.2", "18.1", "18.2", "18.1", "11.1", "15.2", "9.3", "NA", "NA", "NA"), 
  catt = c("Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "NA", "NA", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "NA", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low4", "Low4", "Low4", "Low7", "Low7", "Low7", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "Low10", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Low1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium4", "Medium4", "Medium7", "Medium7", "Medium10", "Medium10", "Medium10", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium4", "Medium4", "Medium7", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium4", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium4", "Medium4", "Medium7", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "High1", "High2", "High1", "NA", "NA", "NA")
)

dtgr$gbf_ttl <- factor(dtgr$gbf_ttl, levels = unique(dtgr$gbf_ttl))
dtgr$nbt_ttll <- factor(dtgr$nbt_ttll, levels = unique(dtgr$nbt_ttll))
dtgr$catt <- factor(dtgr$catt, levels= c("Low12", "Low11", "Low10", "Low9", "Low8", "Low7", "Low6", "Low5", "Low4", "Low3", "Low2", "Low1", "Low0", 
                       "Medium10", "Medium9", "Medium8", "Medium7", "Medium6", "Medium5", "Medium4", "Medium3", "Medium2", "Medium1", "Medium0",  
                       "High3", "High2", "High1", "High0", "High00"))


pt1 <- c("Target 1", "Target 2", "Target 3", "Target 4", "Target 5", "Target 6", "Target 7", "Target 8", "Target 9", "Target 10", "Target 11")
dtgr1 <- dtgr %>% filter(gbf_ttl %in% pt1)
```

My best efforts have led me to use:
(1) **geom_quasirandom()** (rather than **geom_point()** or **geom_jitter()**), which works just fine with **coord_polar()** but some level of ovelap persists that makes reading the labels impossible - especially as I need to repeat this for 69 cases, each with a different number of points
Here is what it looks like:

```
sep1 <- seq(0.5, 10.5, 1)

ggplot(data = dtgr1, aes(x = gbf_ttl, y = catt)) +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(sim = factor(c("High", "Medium", "Low"), levels = c("High", "Medium", "Low")), 
                              start = c(0.5, 5.5, 16.5), end = c(5.5, 16.5, 28.5)), inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = Inf, ymin = start, ymax = end, fill = sim), 
            colour = "black", size = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00A54A", "#59DC3D", "#AFFF57")) +
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dtgr$catt))) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = sep1, colour = "black") + 
  geom_quasirandom(size = 10, show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.8, dodge.width = 0, color = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = nbt_ttll), size = 4, fontface = "bold", color = "black", 
            position = position_quasirandom(width = 0.8, dodge.width = 0)) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "x") + 
  theme(line = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=8), legend.text = element_text(size=7), legend.key = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
```

[image: Plot with overlap I am able to produce]

(2) **geom_dotplot()**, which does exactly what I want with the dots themselves (stacked, side-by-side)... but it does not work with coord_polar(): "*`geom_dotplot()` does not work properly with non-linear coordinates*"
Here is how I wish the dots were represented, so that I could then adapt the coordinates to polar:

```
ggplot(dtgr1, aes(x = gbf_ttl, y = catt)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 1.2) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dtgr1$catt))) #+ coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

[image: Non-overlapped non-polar plot I wish to produce]

Any thoughts as to how overcome the limitations of either approach so as to achieve the "best of both worlds"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change size in approach 1:  `geom_quasirandom(size = 6, show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.8, dodge.width = 0, color = "pink") +` 
  `geom_text(aes(label = nbt_ttll), size = 2, fontface = "bold", color = "black", 
            position = position_quasirandom(width = 0.8, dodge.width = 0)) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the factors to numeric values and space the points out as they would be in a dotplot. Ultimately though, you simply  run out of room within some segments to fit all the dots; you need to either shrink the text, enlarge the plot or accept overlaps. The following seems like a reasonable comprimise:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

dtgr2 <- dtgr1 %>%
  mutate(catt = fct_rev(catt),
         catt = replace(catt, catt == "NA", NA),
         gbf_ttl = droplevels(gbf_ttl)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))

dtgr2 %>%
  group_by(catt, gbf_ttl) %>%
  mutate(n = (row_number() - mean(n()))/n(),
         n = (n - mean(n))*0.9 + as.numeric(gbf_ttl)) %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(catt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, y)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -5, ymax = c(29, 16, 5),
           fill = c("#b0fa58", "#59dc3d", "#01a54b")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, 10.5, 1)) +
  geom_point(size = 11, fill = "white", shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(label = nbt_ttll), size = 3.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 29)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:11,,
                     labels = levels(dtgr2$gbf_ttl)[1:11],
                     limits = c(0.5, 11.5)) +
  coord_curvedpolar() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = 2))
```

[image]

Personally, I think putting all those numbers on a plot is messy, and makes it hard to discern patterns. If you want a repository of numbers for reference, a table would be better. Alternatively, make use of color to show patterns in your data, rather than using it purely for decoration:

```r
dtgr2 %>%
  group_by(catt, gbf_ttl) %>%
  mutate(n = (row_number() - mean(n()))/n(),
         n = (n - mean(n))*0.9 + as.numeric(gbf_ttl)) %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(catt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, y)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -5, ymax = c(29, 16, 5),
           fill = c('gray95', "gray85", "gray75"), color = "gray50") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, 10.5, 1)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, aes(fill = as.numeric(nbt_ttll)), shape = 21) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 29)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:11,,
                     labels = levels(dtgr2$gbf_ttl)[1:11],
                     limits = c(0.5, 11.5)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(NULL, low = "gray50", high = "red3", limits = c(0, 30)) +
  coord_curvedpolar() +
  theme_void(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = 2),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is gorgeous! You are a gentleman and a scholar, kind sir! Thank you a million times over, @AllanCameron, @Allan, @Cameron, @Allan Cameron, `@Allan Cameron`, Allan Cameron!